# Can't install Sample Data Magento2 CE on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: magento2, php-7, sample-data

I Installed Magento 2.0.18, I have PHP 7.0.30 installed on my system.

I can't get the sample data installed in my system. All I see is blank Luma theme saying your content goes here.

[image: Blank Theme]

I have run following commands:

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
bin/magento setup:di:compile

bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Modules status

[image: Modules Enabled]

Given credentials from my Magento account to deploy the sample data.

Ran following command to set permission from magento directory:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Still can't able to get it working. been trying different references from 2 days online.

**PS: I ran all commands above as a magento user created suggested by Magento docs, magento user is in www-data group.**

Comment: hi @sai kiran whether you r looking for home page with luma theme and products and default featuers?

Comment: no, see the screenshot attached

Comment: that means whether you would like to install M2 with sample data?

Comment: Yes @NagarajuKasa

Comment: try with the reference link http://m4s0.com/install-magento-2-with-sample-data/ locally and if it work then try the same in server